# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ENTRIESn_hourly

Tags: python, bigdata, key-value, reducers

so i am trying to write a map/reduce code to analyze the total entries by unit of the NYC subway.

my mapper code generated a .txt file as demanded by the project.

```
import sys

def mapper():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split(",")
        if len(data) == 22:
            Unnamed,UNIT,DATEn,TIMEn,Hour,DESCn,ENTRIESn_hourly,EXITSn_hourly,maxpressurei,maxdewpti,mindewpti,minpressurei,meandewpti,meanpressurei,fog,rain,meanwindspdi,mintempi,meantempi,maxtempi,precipi,thunder = data
            print "{0}\t{1}".format(UNIT,ENTRIESn_hourly)

sys.stdin = open('turnstile_data_master_with_weather.csv')
sys.stdout = open('mapper_result.txt', 'w')
mapper()
```

the file mapper_result.txt is correct, it's a 2 column file(key/value) of the entries by unit of NYC subway.
so ,then, i went to write de reducer code to sum all the values by unit, as follows:

```
import sys

def reducer():
    entriesTotal = 0
    oldKey = None

    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        if len(data) != 2:
            continue
        thisKey,thisEntry = data
        if oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
            print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey,entriesTotal)

            entriesTotal = 0
        oldKey = thisKey
        entriesTotal += float(thisEntry)
    if oldKey != None:
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey, entriesTotal)

sys.stdin = open('mapper_result.txt')
sys.stdout = open('reducer_result.txt', 'w')
reducer()

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8ec50e7ee920> in <module>()
     21 sys.stdin = open('mapper_result.txt')
     22 sys.stdout = open('reducer_result.txt', 'w')
---> 23 reducer()

<ipython-input-28-8ec50e7ee920> in reducer()
     15             entriesTotal = 0
     16         oldKey = thisKey
---> 17         entriesTotal += float(thisEntry)
     18     if oldKey != None:
     19         print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey, entriesTotal)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ENTRIESn_hourly
```

maybe it s a problem converting the strings in .txt file in floats.
anyone have an idea?

Comment: can you add an example of the data?

Comment: `ENTRIESn_hourly` is a string and the reducer() function cannot convert it to a `float` on this line: `entriesTotal += float(thisEntry)`. This error is easy to reproduce on your own: `float("junk")`

Comment: UNIT ENTRIESn_hourly
R001 0.0
R001 217.0
R001 890.0
R001 2451.0
R001 4400.0
R001 3372.0
R002 0.0
R002 42.0
R002 50.0
R002 316.0
R002 633.0
R002 639.0
R003 0.0
R003 0.0
R003 0.0
R003 0.0      after the mapper. so the reducer should get this and sum by unit

Comment: use `print` for every instance of `data` in your for loop and that should demonstrate where the problem is.

Comment: i did that, and it shows alwasys in the same line "  entriesTotal += float(thisEntry)". apparently it doesnt convert the string in mapper_result.txt to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so i managed to finish it by using the try...except in the thisEntry.
here is the final code:

```
import sys

def reducer():
    entriesTotal = 0
    oldKey = None

    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        if len(data) != 2:
            continue
        thisKey,thisEntry = data
        if oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
            print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey,entriesTotal)

            entriesTotal = 0
        oldKey = thisKey
        try:
            entriesTotal += float(thisEntry)
        except:
            print thisEntry


    if oldKey != None:
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(oldKey, entriesTotal)

sys.stdin = open('mapper_result.txt', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('reducer_result.txt', 'w')
reducer()
```